# How can I manage Twig inheritance across multiple bundles?

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm (still) a beginner with Symfony and have been reading about [three-level inheritance](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#three-level-inheritance) with Twig.

If you define blocks in your bundle their names might be bundle specific and not match block names defined in your app `base.html.twig` or other bundles, or even the names could be the same but the usage could be different.

- Has anyone found this to be a problem?
- Are there ways to manage this, will overriding templates under `app/` help?
- Are there any conventions for block names or anything else that will minimise maintenance problems?

Answer (score 0):

Block names should have some sort of relation to whats going to place within the block. so if you have css styles within a block you would call it Stylesheets, and for javascript files call it JavaScript. As far bundles, create a layout.html.twig within the views folder and extend the base.html.twig.

Comment: Dave, thanks for your reply. This actually gives a good example - you suggest using `Stylesheets` and `Javascript` where several examples in the Symfony Book use `stylesheets` and `javascripts`. With my limited understanding I imagine I would need to start overriding templates just to cope with this subtle difference in some 3rd party bundle.